# how import qrcode-generator into angular 2 app?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use [qrcode-generator](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator) in my app but no success with my settings even though it's working in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEzqUfrnjehG84wm16De?p=preview), in my app I'm using angular-cli and angular 2.rc-1.
Steps to reproduce:

```
ng new newAppName
cd newAppName
ng serve
```

it works, then.

```
npm i qrcode-generator // (note this is missing the svg support).
ng serve // still work
```

then change the configurations in 2 files.
angular-cli-build.js:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'qrcode-generator/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

and system-config.ts:

```
/**********************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 *********************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'qrcode-generator': 'vendor/qrcode-generator'
};
const packages: any = {
  'vendor/qrcode-generator': {
    main: 'qrcode',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
// ... the rest is the same
```

edit `new-app-name.component.ts` and import the qrcode-geenerator in it like this

```
// vscode underline the qrcode-generator string and complai about not finding it
import * as qrcode from 'qrcode-generator';
```

then `ng serve` which is still running errors out with this message:

> /path/to/project/newAppName/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-jscpZEq5.tmp/0/src/app/new-app-name.component.ts
>   (3, 25): Cannot find module 'qrcode-generator'.

I tried installing the typings for it by adding this to the typings.json file:

```
"globalDependencies": {
    "qrcode-generator": "registry:dt/qrcode-generator#0.0.0+20160412152159"
  }
```

then running:

```
typings i
```

install successful, but still the same error.
angular-cli version:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.5
node: 6.2.0
os: linux x64
```

Am I missing something?
Is there other configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to import this finally thanks to [@JavascriptMick](https://github.com/JavascriptMick) from [angular-cli's gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular-cli?at=574b6ffba78d5a256e38f83f) I did the following, first make the format global:

```
'vendor/qrcode-generator': {
    format: 'global',
    main: 'qrcode.js'
  }
```

then when importing do it this way:

```
import 'qrcode-generator';
declare let qrcode;
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the specific requirements you have, but here is an AngularJS (Version 1) app that features a QR-Code generator:

http://quir.li/qr.html

You can

- enter the text
- select the error code level
- select a size
- View/Copy/download the QR code from the screen

I am the author of said page, but the QR generator is [jsqrencode](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsqrencode/downloads) by tz@execpc.com

My source code is at https://github.com/suterma/quirli/blob/master/website/qr.html

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear I'm using angular 2 with angular-cli I get it to work with qrcode-generator plugin in the plunker example I provided, but couldn't do it in my app with angular-cli, I just need to import it into typescript module.